# Array subset unequal sums

Tags: java

I have a requirement to write a function to divide an array in 2 parts {4,5,2,1,3}, such that sum in first array is greater than in second array but length of 1st array is smaller than that of second.The union of their sums is total sum and they dont have any intersection.So, an answer would be {4,5}.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DP2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr= {5,2,10,4,1,11};
        ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
        //calculate sum
        int finalSum=0;
        /*
        for(int i: arr)
            finalSum+=arr[i];
            */
        int len=arr.length;
        int mid=(len)/2;
        System.out.println(mid);
        int sum=0;
        //initialize 2 pointers

        //will use a stack
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

        int i=0,j=len-1;
        int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        while(i < j ) {
            //int max=Math.max(arr[i], arr[j]);
        //  System.out.println(max);
            while(stack.size() < mid) {


                max=Math.max(arr[i], arr[j]);
                stack.push(max);
                //System.out.println(stack.size());
            //  System.out.println(stack.peek());
                i++;
                j--;
            }

        //  max=Math.max(arr[i], arr[j]);
            i++;
            j--;

            if(stack.size() < mid  && stack.peek() < max  ) {




                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(max);


                }




        }


        while(!stack.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(stack.pop());




        }
    }
```

It wont return the expected answer. It is not popping out from stack as I had coded to do. Can someone please help what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong, everything works as expected. The only problem was that the popping operation was giving you the result in reverse order. I have fixed that in the code below:

```
Integer[] result = new Integer[stack.size()];
for (int i1 = result.length - 1; i1 >= 0 && !stack.isEmpty(); i1--) {
    result[i1] = stack.pop();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

**Output**
`[4, 5]`

**EDIT:** As requested here is a full solution to your problem:

```
/**
 * Convert an array of primitive numbers to Integer objects.
 */
private static Integer[] intToInteger(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
}

/**
 * Converts a primitive integer array to an ArrayList.
 */
private static ArrayList<Integer> intArrayTolist(int[] array) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intToInteger(array)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr0 = { 5, 2, 10, 4, 1, 11 };

    /* determine the size of the first array */
    float quotient = (float)arr0.length / 2;
    int mid = (int) Math.floor(quotient);

    int size = quotient != mid ? mid : mid - 1;

    /* Initialize arrays here */
    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[size];
    Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[arr0.length - mid];

    List<Integer> list = intArrayTolist(arr0);

    /* Populate the first array with largest values
     * found within the main array
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        /*
         * Find out the largest value in the main array
         * and add that value to the first array
         */
        arr1[i] = java.util.Collections.max(list);
        list.remove(arr1[i]);
    }

    arr2 = list.toArray(arr2);
    int sum = Arrays.stream(arr0).sum();

    System.out.println("First array: " + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println("Second array: " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
    System.out.println("Sum of all numbers: " + sum);
}
```

**Output**

```
First array: [11, 10]
Second array: [5, 2, 4, 1]
Sum of all numbers: 33
```

Note that it might not be as elegant I would have hopped but it gets the job done. I will see if I can do some further cleaning and optimizing as I feel there is a lot of redundancies in there. It's just a quick mock up so you can have something that actually works.

Comment: But what I am trying to say is this should return minimum length subarray and max sum. If i use {1,4,6,7,9,11,10}, it should return {11,10}

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a full solution to your problem. Let me know if it works for you and if there is anything more it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I used recursion. This is the way I did it:

```
@Test
public void stackoverflow() {
    int[] array = { 39, 2, 3, 40, 0, 0, 0 };
    System.out.println("index is " + method(array, 0));
}

String method(int[] array, int i) {
    if (i < array.length / 2 && sum(array, 0, i) > sum(array, i + 1, array.length - 1)) {
        return "the sub array goes from 0 to " + i;
    }
    else if (i >= array.length / 2 && sum(array, array.length - 1 - i + array.length / 2, array.length - 1) > sum(array, 0, array.length - i - 2 + array.length / 2)) {
        int index = array.length - 1 - i + array.length / 2;
        return "the sub array goes from " + index + " to " + (array.length - 1);
    }
    return method(array, i + 1);
}

int sum(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        sum = sum + array[k];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is the explanation: you start from position 0 of the array. If the sum of the element at [0] is greater than the sum from position [1] to [n-1], you are done. If not, you call the same logic, comparing the sum from [0] to [1] versus [2] to [n-1]. Since you are looking for the smallest array, when you hit the half of the array (n/2), then you do the same starting from the end of the array.

My logic returns the index of the array. The index represents either the last element or the first element of the sub array which contains the greater sum. For example, in this case:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 1, 2, 3 }
```

it will return "4". [4] is this element:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 1, 2, 3 }
               *
```

Is clear here that if the index > n/2, then the sub array goes from index to n-1. If not, then the sub array goes from 0 to n/2.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test this?